# BGE script error: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I've been dabbling in Blender's Game Engine, so I thought it was time to take it to the next level and use scripts to control my game, but now I have a problem; I keep getting this error (only printing error message):

```
mainScript.py, line 28
   if PlayerControls.playerMain['isInCover'] == 0
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

My code:

```
def toggleProne():
  if PlayerControls.playerMain['isInCover'] == 0
      PlayerControls.playerMain['isCrouched'] = 0
      PlayerControls.playerMain['isStanding'] = 0
      PlayerControls.playerMain['isProne'] = 1
  return;
```

Removing the if-statement and adjusting the indentation (as a result of the removed if-statement) allows the code to be compiled - until it finds the next if statement and errors out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write an [if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) in python you need a colon at the end of the condition then the rest gets indented.
Like this

```
if a == b:
    print("yep")
```

So your code would be like this.

```
def toggleProne(): 
    if PlayerControls.playerMain['isInCover'] == 0:
        PlayerControls.playerMain['isCrouched'] = 0
        PlayerControls.playerMain['isStanding'] = 0
        PlayerControls.playerMain['isProne'] = 1
    return;
```

Personally, I would use a var for `PlayerControls.playerMain`, it would save you from having that whole thing four times.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really is the small things that cause the biggest of problems in code! ;)

Comment: indeed. computer are so picky. they do exactly what we tell them to do, even if that is not what we meant.

Comment: @David "HAL, make coffee, add milk and 10 tablespoons of sugar" ... "Sure, Dave, I can do that."